# Any pointers to smallest CLI runtime?

Tags: .net, mono, runtime, jit

I'm looking for smallest CLI subset implementation possible.

For now, even an interpreter will do, but I am really looking for a 
JITted runtime. I do not even need anything from the standard runtime 
apart from core classes like System.Object and Enum etc. It also needs 
to be portable and least dependent on underlying system.

I have considered mono and it is quite heavy. Cutting down mono down to 
my requirements is a huge task. I wonder if it has been done already. 
I'm currently looking at pnet, which includes a 'tiny' build.

Comment: What sort of environment or platform is this for? Browser? Microcontroller? Low spec PC? PDA/Smart Phone?

Comment: I will be using it to write stopwatch for a digital wristwatch  :)

Comment: Re "digital wristwatch"... Micro Framework was actually first used for watches... no, really.

Comment: Proof - http://msmobiles.com/news.php/5199.html - and here's the watch: http://direct.msn.com/

Comment: thanks Marc, this is awesomely interesting :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it has what you are looking for but Microsoft recently open sourced the [.Net Micro](http://www.microsoft.com/netmf/) Framework, might be worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

The .NET Micro Framework is an IL interpreter, and is very small. It is not, however, fully featured - you don't get generics, and some things like properties work differently (there is no PropertyInfo).

Others:

- Compact Framework
- Silverlight

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Mono [Linker](http://www.mono-project.com/Linker) with mkbundle.  The idea of it is that it will only link the pieces of Mono that you need, and no more.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Silverlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverlight), though it's somewhat "in-browser".

Answer (score 0):

Your build script may turn out to be a PITA - but [CrossNet](http://crossnet.codeplex.com/) might be a good idea. It compiles MSIL into C++.

So you could land up with no CLR at all :).